# What draws the sort indicator in QHeaderview?

Tags: c++, css, qt

I'm attempting to colorize the backgrounds of a QHeaderView in Qt 4.8 on Linux RHEL 6.8. By all accounts this should be achievable by using a QProxyStyle (as opposed to overloading a QHeaderView, which I still don't get how to do properly when using the Creator, but that's another question/google).

What I don't understand is how it seems that by my understanding drawControl should be getting invoked to draw the sort indicator, but the flags I'm receiving never have the State_Up/Down I'm expecting, nor does it get hit for it.

[image: Three columns, brightly colored but with an indicator visible despite being colored AFTER the control draws]

[image: Three columns, each colored with an alpha, but the indicator bleeds through]

Drawn with alpha, we see that A) the arrows are huge, and B) the indicator is only one shade dark--we'd expect it to also have a box around it if were drawn by drawControl as the documentation seems to indicate.

[image: Same boxes as above, but with a smaller arrow and not colorized]

Here, with the stylesheet applied, we have less goofily sized arrows, but the StyleProxy isn't being invoked at all! I believe this is a known issue, though.

**Since I can't seem to override the drawing of the indicators in my Proxy, what am I to do?**

## MCV

## Header

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QProxyStyle>


QT_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(QTreeWidget)
QT_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(QTreeWidgetItem)

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MyProxy : public QProxyStyle
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyProxy(QStyle* style) : QProxyStyle(style) {}

    virtual void drawControl(ControlElement element, const QStyleOption *option, QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget = 0) const;
};


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow() {};

private:
    void init();
    QTreeWidgetItem* makeItem(QTreeWidgetItem* parent = NULL);

    QTreeWidget* m_tree;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

## Source

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QTreeWidgetItem>
#include <QStyleOptionHeader>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHeaderView>

void MyProxy::drawControl(ControlElement element, const QStyleOption *option, QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget) const
{
    if (element >= CE_Header && element <= CE_HeaderLabel) {
        const QStyleOptionHeader* ho = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionHeader*>(option);

        // expectation: we'd be able to override all the colors that aren't being drawn here

        painter->save();
        QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
        painter->restore();

        // as an example, just blart all over everything
        QColor col(Qt::GlobalColor(ho->section+Qt::red));
        //col.setAlphaF(0.3); // if you want to see what you've painted over
        painter->fillRect(option->rect, QBrush(col));

    } else {
        QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
    }
}


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
   init();


    m_tree->setStyle(new MyProxy(m_tree->style()));

    // if this is in, our proxy never gets called with the header, but the arrows aren't huge
    // without it, we never get hit for the indicator anyway
//        m_tree->header()->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::down-arrow { width: 16px; height:10px; subcontrol-position: center right;} "
//                              "QHeaderView::section { padding-right:2px; } "
//                              );

}

// handle the stuff to make the example go
void MainWindow::init() {
    resize(400,200);
    setWindowTitle("Without StyleSheet");

    QWidget* m = new QWidget(this);
    this->setCentralWidget(m);

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(m);
    m->setLayout(layout);

    m_tree = new QTreeWidget(m);
    m_tree->setSortingEnabled(true);
    m_tree->setColumnCount(3);
    m_tree->header()->setProperty("showSortIndicator", QVariant(true));
    m_tree->header()->setDefaultAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    layout->addWidget(m_tree);

    QTreeWidgetItem* item = makeItem();
    item->setText(0, "Item 1:1");
    item->setText(1, "Item 1:2");

    item = makeItem();
    item->setText(0, "Item 2");

    item = makeItem();
    item->setText(0, "Item 3 - Children");

    QTreeWidgetItem* kid = makeItem(item);
    kid->setText(1, "Paw Patrol!");

    QStringList labels;
    labels.append("Column\n1");
    labels.append("Column\n2");
    labels.append("Column\n3");
    m_tree->setHeaderLabels(labels);
    m_tree->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    m_tree->header()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
}

QTreeWidgetItem* MainWindow::makeItem(QTreeWidgetItem* parent)  {
    QTreeWidgetItem* item = parent ? new QTreeWidgetItem(parent) : new QTreeWidgetItem(m_tree);
    for(int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
        QColor col( Qt::GlobalColor(Qt::darkRed+i));
        col.setAlphaF(0.2);
        item->setBackgroundColor(i, col);
    }

    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it's drawPrimitive. That said, I'm still at a loss as to how to properly color the background of the labels/headers. The above approach, colorizing with an alpha drawn last seems... silly.

```
void ObjHeaderProxyStyle::drawPrimitive(PrimitiveElement element, const QStyleOption *option, QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget) const
{
    if( element ==  PE_IndicatorHeaderArrow )
    {
    // ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to affect the size is by using QProxyStyle::pixelMetric to shrink it. This reduces both the visual size and also the margins around the labels, keeping everything sized more correctly.

```
int MyProxy::pixelMetric(PixelMetric metric, const QStyleOption *option, const QWidget *widget ) const
{
    if( metric == PM_HeaderMargin )
    {
        return 1; // QStyleHelper::dpiScaled(4.); // the default(ish)
    }
    return QProxyStyle::pixelMetric(metric, option, widget);
}
```

Why it doesn't seem to ever listen to PM_HeaderMarkSize--"The size of the sort indicator in a header."--is beyond me.